# JavaScript editor component to embed into java application

Tags: java, swing, editor, syntax-highlighting

I have a largish application written in Java with a Swing UI. I am interesting in adding [user scripting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/) via JavaScript. To allow users to edit JS from within the application, I would like to go beyond a simple plain-text JEditorPane, with some kind of syntax-highlighting and smart indentation. The application is LGPL, so the license would need to be LGPL-compatible.

I can use an old version of [jedit-syntax](http://jedit-syntax.sourceforge.net/) (MIT license), but I wonder if there is any actively-maintained project that does something similar, ideally in a maven-aware fashion. I would rather something lightweight - no Eclipse or NetBeans RCPs, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't use it, but looks like what you need and is maintained: http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/

Comment: This component is awesome!

Comment: Wins the prize -- it is similar enough to the jsyntaxpane, but it is easier to integrate.

Answer (score 3):

Really good Swing-Editor for JavaScript (and some other languages) is JSyntaxPane. http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/

It has syntax-highlighting and some other usefull features (line-numbering, parenthesis highlighting). It also can be customized (for example if you have special extensions-keywords).

Editor is Distributed under Apache 2.0. I don'T know whether it's LGPL compatible or not.

Comment: Looking into it - seems promising. I understand bundling apache2-licensed code within LGPL is ok (apache is less restrictive); vice-versa would not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can work with Swing, but I would recommend [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/). Since you are on java, try [this](http://code.google.com/p/tinymce-gwt/) version or the [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/djproject/) implementation and use as provided [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Swing-Library/DJ-Project-0.9.9/chrriis/dj/nativeswing/swtimpl/demo/examples/htmleditor/TinyMCEExample.java.htm)